# Printing dictionary keys/key values causing unintended newlines?

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I'm writing a function that reads lines from a file and makes a list, which is then passed through loops to create a dictionary that keeps each line as a key and then increments the key value. Basically, my only issue is the way it is printing out is not as I intended. Code here:

```
import re
import string

def readInputFile():
    print("Reading \"GroceryList.txt\"")
    f = open("GroceryList.txt")
    itemList = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    itemDict = { }
    
    for ln in itemList:
        i = 0
        itemCount = 0
        while i < len(itemList):
            if ln == itemList[i]:
                itemCount += 1
                itemList.pop(i)
            itemDict[ln] = itemCount
            i += 1
    
    for key in itemDict:
        print("{}: {}".format(key, itemDict[key]))
```

For whatever reason, it's printing like this:

***Spinach***

***: 5***

***Broccoli***

***: 1***

*... etc.*

whereas my intention was for it to be:

***Spinach: 5***

***Broccoli: 1***

*... etc.*

The dictionary is setting itself as intended, with correct keys and key values, it's just printing in this way and I'm not sure why? I'm still a rookie so I'm not exactly sure how to correct this.

Comment: It'll be pretty clear why this happens if you do `for k in itemDict: print(repr(k))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading each line from the file - this will still have the newlines at the end of values. You can remove whitespace and new lines by calling `.strip()` on the string:

```
itemDict[ln.strip()] = itemCount
```

If the goal is to count the number of times the ingredients appear in the shopping list, you can use the built-in `Counter` class under `collections` instead.

```py
from collections import Counter

...

item_count = Counter(itemList)
#  item_count will now be a dictionary-like object with the 
#  line as the key and the number of occurrences as the value.
```

To strip the newline from each list in your file, you can apply `strip` to every value in the `itemList`:

```
item_count = Counter(map(lambda s: s.strip(), itemList))
```

You can then print out the `item_count` counter in the same manner as you already do.

Comment: Wow, this is my first time posting a question, you guys are quick lol!

The .strip() function solved everything. Unfortunately I'm only working with what my school teaches me at the moment so I wasn't familiar with the Counter class or the syntax with map(lambda s: ...etc) and whatnot, but regardless I've got it figured out now with .strip().

Much appreciated!